# SQL - query de minutos trascurridos

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT BELNR_ID
    ,BELPOS_ID
    ,DocDate
    ,AUFTRAG
    ,APLATZ_ID
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ANFZEIT, 103) AS 'Fecha Inicio'
    ,RIGHT(ANFZEIT, 7) AS 'Hora Inicio'
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ENDZEIT, 103) AS 'Fecha Fin'
    ,RIGHT(ENDZEIT, 7) AS 'Hora fin'
    ,ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, RIGHT(ANFZEIT, 7), RIGHT(ENDZEIT, 7))) AS 'MinutosTranscurridos'
    ,ZEIT
    ,LEFT(APLATZ_ID, 5) AS 'Maquina'
    ,LEFT(AUFTRAG, 2) AS 'Turno'
FROM BEAS_ARBZEIT
```

Donde estoy ocupando

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, RIGHT(ANFZEIT, 7), RIGHT(ENDZEIT, 7))) as 'MinutosTranscurridos'
```

`ABS` para convertir a positivo los datos y el `DATEDIFF` para sacar los minutos trascurridos, pero tengo un pequeño detalle.

Cuando el rango es dentro del mismo día durante las 24 horas sí me manda el rango correcto de minutos transcurridos, pero cuando el rango abarca dos días me manda un rato erróneo.

**Ejemplos:**

> ```
> 19/04/2017     1:00AM    19/04/2017     6:00AM    300 MIN  "esto es ok"
>
> 18/04/2017    10:00PM    19/04/2017     1:00AM    1260 MIN  "ESTO NO ESTA BIEN"
> ```

---

**Actualización en base a las respuestas recibidas**

Estoy restructurando la consulta con algo similar a lo que comenta @Patricio Moracho  estoy restructurando la consulta con algo similar a lo que comenta @Patricio Moracho

```
DECLARE @ANFZEIT DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDZEIT DATETIME 
SET @ANFZEIT = 'select ANFZEIT from BEAS_ARBZEIT';
SET @ENDZEIT = 'select ENDZEIT from BEAS_ARBZEIT';
select BELNR_ID,BELPOS_ID,DocDate,AUFTRAG,APLATZ_ID,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ANFZEIT,103) AS 'Fecha Inicio', 
        RIGHT(ANFZEIT, 7) AS 'Hora Inicio',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ENDZEIT,103) AS 'Fecha Fin', 
        RIGHT(ENDZEIT, 7) AS 'Hora fin',
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@ANFZEIT,@ENDZEIT) as 'MinutosTranscurridos',
        ZEIT,LEFT(APLATZ_ID,5) AS 'Maquina',LEFT(AUFTRAG,2) AS 'Turno' from BEAS_ARBZEIT
```

pero me marca este error

> ```
> La conversión falló al convertir la fecha y / o
> el tiempo de una cadena de caracteres.
> ```

Comment: es consulta en SQL

Comment: Asumo que por la función `DATEDIFF` estás utilizando SQL Server, ¿es correcto?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se ve, los campos `ANFZEIT` y `ENDZEIT` ya son de tipo fecha, por lo que no es necesario convertirlos a otro tipo de datos antes de obtener la diferencia.  Simplemente utiliza:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, ANFZEIT, ENDZEIT)) as 'Minutos Transcurridos'
```

Ya que como menciona @PatricioMoracho en su respuesta, al utilizar `RIGHT(ANFZEIT, 7)` primero convierte la fecha y hora a una cadena de caracteres de acuerdo al formato estándar para la configuración regional y luego toma los últimos 7 caracteres, para luego volver a convertir al tipo `DATETIME` pero sin la parte de la fecha, por lo que los horarios son del mismo día (dependiendo del gestor de base de datos utilizado puede ser 1900-01-01 o algo similar) y entonces de ahí el resultado.

Comment: si asi es solo que cuando estan dentro del mismo dia si me manda la informacion correcta, pero cuando cambian de dia me mandan mal la informacion.Ejemplos:

    19/04/2017     1:00AM    19/04/2017     6:00AM    300 MIN  "esto es ok"

    18/04/2017    10:00PM    19/04/2017     1:00AM    1260 MIN  "ESTO NO ESTA BIEN"

Comment: Te sugiero que hagas la modificación que indico y luego edites tu pregunta original con el resultado.  Estoy seguro que debe funcionar correctamente.  Es lo mismo que te ha sugerido @Flxtr.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es más simple de lo que parece ser el problema, solo es cuestión de poner la diferencia de las fechas con:

```
DATEDIFF(mi, ANFZEIT, ENDZEIT) AS 'MinutosTranscurridos'
```

Y si es necesario manejar los negativos sería con:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, ANFZEIT, ENDZEIT)) AS 'MinutosTranscurridos'
```

Finalmente, tu *query* quedaría de la siguente manera:

```
SELECT BELNR_ID
    ,BELPOS_ID
    ,DocDate
    ,AUFTRAG
    ,APLATZ_ID
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ANFZEIT, 103) AS 'Fecha Inicio'
    ,RIGHT(ANFZEIT, 7) AS 'Hora Inicio'
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ENDZEIT, 103) AS 'Fecha Fin'
    ,RIGHT(ENDZEIT, 7) AS 'Hora fin'
    ,ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, ANFZEIT, ENDZEIT)) AS 'MinutosTranscurridos'
    ,ZEIT
    ,LEFT(APLATZ_ID, 5) AS 'Maquina'
    ,LEFT(AUFTRAG, 2) AS 'Turno'
FROM BEAS_ARBZEIT
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/JZAH55218)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), ANFZEIT,120) AS SMALLDATETIME),
   CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), ENDZEIT, 120) AS SMALLDATETIME)) as 'MinutosTranscurridos'
```

**Nota:** Se entiende que por default la BD maneja horario militar (24:00; es decir la 1:00 PM lo retorna como 13:00; caso contrario aumentar Char(16) según sea la longitud de caracteres)

Answer (score 0):

Estoy re-estructurando la consulta con algo similar a lo que comenta @Patricio Moracho:

```
DECLARE @ANFZEIT DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDZEIT DATETIME 
SET @ANFZEIT = 'select ANFZEIT from BEAS_ARBZEIT';
SET @ENDZEIT = 'select ENDZEIT from BEAS_ARBZEIT';
select BELNR_ID,BELPOS_ID,DocDate,AUFTRAG,APLATZ_ID,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ANFZEIT,103) AS 'Fecha Inicio', 
        RIGHT(ANFZEIT, 7) AS 'Hora Inicio',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ENDZEIT,103) AS 'Fecha Fin', 
        RIGHT(ENDZEIT, 7) AS 'Hora fin',
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@ANFZEIT,@ENDZEIT) as 'MinutosTranscurridos',
        ZEIT,LEFT(APLATZ_ID,5) AS 'Maquina',LEFT(AUFTRAG,2) AS 'Turno' from BEAS_ARBZEIT
```

Pero me marca este error:

> La conversión falló al convertir la fecha y / o el tiempo de una
>   cadena de caracteres.

Comment: Te sugiero editar la pregunta original para agregar los nuevos detalles en lugar de agregar una respuesta.  Por lo pronto el problema está en la asignación de los valores de las variables `@ANFZEIT` y `@ENDZEIT` que de entrada no son necesarias y simplemente debes usar la expresión que he indicado en mi respuesta.